# Looking help to write a script to merge the columns (that are common as one separated by comma

Tags: oracle11g

I am looking for help in writing a script to accomplish below

I would like to merge the columns (that are common as one separated by comma delimiter) for each id.

Table A

```
id i_part ipart_ps ipart_size   j_part  j_part_ps j_part_size k_part k_part_p

1   XXXX   4,c         10         AAAA   3L+2         7       BBBB        3,c

2   XXXX   4,c         15         CCCC   3L+2         9       KKKK        3,c

3   XXXX   4,c         13         DDDD   3L+2         10      RRRR        3,c
```

Table A

```
id  part           position       size
 1  XXXX,AAAA,BBBB  4,c,3L+2,3,c   10,7
 2  XXXX,CCCC,KKKK  4,c,3L+2,3,c   15,9
 3  XXXX,DDDD,RRRR  4,c,3L+2,3,c   13,10
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how the data appears at the moment and how you want it to appear?

Comment: Table A 
id i_part ipart_ps ipart_size   j_part  j_part_ps j_part_size k_part  k_part_Ps
1   XXXX   4,c         10         AAAA      3L+2        7      BBBB       3,c 
2   XXXX   4,c         15         CCCC     3L+2        9      KKKK       3,c
3   XXXX   4,c         13         DDDD     3L+2        10    RRRR      3,c

Comment: able A

id  part                         position                size
 i   XXXX,AAAA,BBBB     4,c,3L+2,3,c        10,7
 2  XXXX,CCCC,KKKK    4,c,3L+2,3,c        15,9
 3  XXXX,DDDD,RRRR   4,c,3L+2,3,c        13,10

Comment: Easy to do, but WHY do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,
       i_part     || ',' || j_part     || ',' || k_part  as part,
       ipart_ps   || ',' || jpart_ps   || ',' || kpart_p as position,
       ipart_size || ',' || jpart_size                   as size
from   table_A;
```

Now, just because you can do something, it doesn't mean you should do it. In this case you probably shouldn't.